# how to add columns to database table that are not contained in Entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, h2

If I want to have DB table with scheme
id|column1|rest of columns...

such as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SampleEntity")
class SampleEntity(
        @Id @GeneratedValue val id: Long,
)
```

how can I add columns to table such that the table has these columns, but my entity does not?

I would like to be able to add these columns programmatically with a for loop. But any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your use case. Then why using JPA?

Comment: Have you already tried creating the `SampleEntity` table and adding whatever columns (having the `ID` one already there)?

Comment: Are any of these columns for foreign keys ? In that case, JPA generates them for you (renameable).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alter table programatically just use spring-jdbc (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate) which will allow you to execute SQL queries thus make changes to table programmatically.

It is completely ok if your entity doesn't have all the columns - columns that don't have matching attributes inside of the class just will be ignored by the entity in Spring JPA. Alternatively, you could just use spring-jdbc with a custom row-mapper.